# ZombieNet + Kuberntetes + macOS

Tags: zombienet

I'm trying to run ZombieNet on macOS with Kubernetes. I've succeded to run it with native option, but Kubernetes fails with an error:

```
⚠ Can not access kubernetes, please check your config.
```

I installed Kubernetes through Docker Desctop and "kubectl version --client" command shows an output:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

My config is:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 100

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"
```

My command is:
zombienet-macos -p kubernetes spawn kubernetes-network.toml

Comment: Hi Denis, zombienet run this command in order to validate the access to the provider `kubectl cluster-info`. Can you run that command in your terminal?
Thanks!

Comment: kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

Comment: Can you also check this file ` more ~/.kube/config` to see if you have other clusters in there?

Comment: apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0(long string here)
    server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
  name: docker-desktop
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
    user: docker-desktop
  name: docker-desktop
current-context: docker-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0(long string here)
    client-key-data: LS0(long string here)

Comment: That looks ok, I will add more debug to the next version of zombienet so we can debug why you get this error. I will ping you to test it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look forward it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed after updating macOS, Docker Desktop and Resetting Kubernetes Cluster through Docker Desktop

Comment: Great!, please post any other question you have. Thanks!